# Angular: как подписать колонки и номера строк для таблицы с кораблями игры "Морской бой"?

Tags: typescript, angular

Изучаю Angular, решил сделать игру "Морской бой", но застрял на следующем - как подписать колонки и строки?
"Красиво" удалось только подписать колонки, но вот со строками - беда. Получается что таблица уезжает.

Как поместить таблицу внутрь?

Код:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkpsca
 [image: Имеющийся результат]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам бы лучше подтянуть html перед изучением angular

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пишете в стиль css класс

```css
.no_border {
  border: none !important;
}
```

и затем этот класс добавляете в стр 8 и 13

Comment: спасибо. а как сделать так, чтобы там, где буквы и цифры границ небыло?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код текстом, а не картинками.

Comment: Да, у меня как то комп затупил - не смог скопировать текст - хз почему, не стал разбираться - в итоге тупо перегрузил комп, помогло